# 'return ' is outside of funtion error keras predict value

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, caffe

I am trying to fetch image from URL. Show a output on another file.I am using keras and tensorflow to run a code but return function is not working how to solve this ? I got results from another file

```
    def get_score(file, model=weapon_model):
    tmp_filename = ""
    if file.find('http') != -1:
        random_text =  "".join([random.choice(string.ascii_letters[:26]) for i in range(15)])
        tmp_filename = "res/" + random_text + "out.jpg"
        if not os.path.isdir('res/'):
            os.mkdir("res/")
        URL = file
        c = urllib3.PoolManager()
        with c.request('GET', URL, preload_content=False) as resp, open(tmp_filename, "wb") as out_file:
            shutil.copyfileobj(resp, out_file)
        resp.release_conn()
        file = tmp_filename
        m,n = 50,50
        im = Image.open(file);
        imrs = im.resize((m,n))
        imrs=img_to_array(imrs)/255;
        imrs=imrs.transpose(2,0,1);
        imrs=imrs.reshape(3,m,n);
        x=[];
        x.append(imrs);
        x=np.array(x);
        predictions = weapon_model.predict(x)[:,1]
        #predictions = weapon_model.predict(x)
        print (predictions)
        print ("Weapon score:  ", predictions[1])
        return predictions
```

Comment: There is no `return` in your code. It also seems incorrectly indented.

Comment: am using return function itz not working...

Comment: This has nothing to do with keras or any other library. Your indentation is messed up and it's a key feature of Python since there are no curly braces on code blocks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try below indentation code.

```
def get_score(file, model=weapon_model):
    tmp_filename = ""
    if file.find('http') != -1:
        random_text =  "".join([random.choice(string.ascii_letters[:26]) for i in range(15)])
        tmp_filename = "res/" + random_text + "out.jpg"
        if not os.path.isdir('res/'):
            os.mkdir("res/")
        URL = file
        c = urllib3.PoolManager()
        with c.request('GET', URL, preload_content=False) as resp, open(tmp_filename, "wb") as out_file:
            shutil.copyfileobj(resp, out_file)
        resp.release_conn()
        file = tmp_filename
        m,n = 50,50
        im = Image.open(file);
        imrs = im.resize((m,n))
        imrs=img_to_array(imrs)/255;
        imrs=imrs.transpose(2,0,1);
        imrs=imrs.reshape(3,m,n);
        x=[];
        x.append(imrs);
        x=np.array(x);
        predictions = weapon_model.predict(x)[:,1]
        #predictions = weapon_model.predict(x)
        print (predictions)
        print ("Weapon score:  ", predictions[1])
        return predictions
```

Comment: same error ...what did you changed above code?

Comment: I haven't modified anything, I did indentation. It was compiled successfully but unable to debug it because don't know what is input parameter weapon_model

Comment: One more thing your input parameter is "model", where you have used this within your code?  predictions = weapon_model.predict(x)[:,1]. Do you want to use "model" in place of "weapon_model"?